# PhoneGap File Transfer Error (code: 3, http_status: 404) on iPhone

Tags: asp.net, ios, xcode, cordova, asmx

I am trying to create an iOS app using PhoneGap that will allow a user to upload photos to a web server.  Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for PhoneGap to load
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // PhoneGap is ready
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Do cool things here...
        }

        function getImage() {
            // Retrieve image file location from specified source
            navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
                                        alert('get picture failed');
                                        },{
                                        quality: 50, 
                                        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                                        }
                                        );

        }
        function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="recFile";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

            var params = new Object();
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";

            options.params = params;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, "http://someWebSite.com/Testing/SaveImage.asmx/SaveImage", win, fail, options, true);
        }

        function win(r) {
            console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        }

        function fail(error) {
            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
            alert("source = " + error.source);
            alert("http_status = " + error.http_status);
            console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
            console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
        }                        
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getImage();">Upload a Photo</button>
</body>
```

Is anything wrong with my index.html file, or is the problem with the ASMX file?

Whenever I try to test this out on a 4th generation iPod Touch, I get the following error message:

```
2012-07-09 16:24:03.257 Test1[916:707] File Transfer Finished with response code 404
2012-07-09 16:24:03.260 Test1[916:707] FileTransferError {
code = 3;
"http_status" = 404;
source = "http://someWebSite.com/Testing/SaveImage.asmx/SaveImage";
target = "file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/5DD01E68-02F7-410B-996A- 2D70BF1A61D3/tmp/cdv_photo_046.jpg";}
2012-07-09 16:24:07.137 Test1[916:707] ERROR: Plugin 'Debug Console' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
```

Comment: have you whitelisted your `someWebSite.com` in Cordova.plist file - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: I have been able to add an iframe of someWebSite.com to my index.html page, and I have already added *.someWebSite.com to the Cordova.plist file.  I'll look over it again, but I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: is the url accessible from your mobile or from your browser??

Comment: Yes, it is accessible.  I changed the web service to just return "Yes!" while I am testing it.  If I go to the URL of the web service in mobile Safari on my iPod touch, it shows "Yes!".  I also see "Yes!" if I embed an iframe of the web service URL in index.html for the mobile app, but it still doesn't work when I try the image upload.

Comment: is your server handler GET/POST compatible?? normal browser request you are testing will go for GET request whereas the upload request will be using POST. you should hurl.it or postman extension to make sure handlers are responding

Comment: How can I test to see if it is GET/POST compatible?  Here is the code for my SaveImage.vb file if that helps.Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://someWebSite.com/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _

Comment: Public Class SaveImage
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function SaveImage() As String
        Dim file As HttpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files("recFile")
        Dim targetFilePath As String = "C:\someLocationOnServer\" + file.FileName
        file.SaveAs(targetFilePath)
        'Return "Yes!"
        Return file.FileName.ToString()

    End Function



End Class

Comment: i have no experience with .net so would not be much help but you can test from your browser and check it is working. Use this Chrome extension which makes it really easy to test the local/remote services with variety of type - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm

Comment: I installed Postman.  I entered the URL for the web service where it says "Enter request URL here".  I selected POST from the drop down list.  Under form-data I typed recFile as the key and chose an image from my computer.  I selected file as type.  I get a .NET error if I do this with the file upload code in there, but I get <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://someWebsite.com/">Yes!</string> if I just have the "Yes!" test code in there.  Is this the correct way to test it?  Does that mean the problem is with the web service?

Comment: i think there is some error on your server side part, you should some example upload code in .net and again test with postman, if that works then it will make it clear

Comment: It would help to see all the code and not just part of it (in this case in your ASMX file), you can substitute the actual values with dummy variables, in any case, see my answer

Comment: Was this ever solved? I'm having the same issue... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this example [Upload image from android phonegap to a server using asmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643708/upload-image-from-android-phonegap-to-a-server-using-asmx)

Or

A simple example

the js

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cordova</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var pictureSource; // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}


</script>




</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var myData = "";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#getDataFromServer").click(function() {
            var imageData = myData;
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : 'http://my.domain.name/saveImage.ashx',
                data : {
                    image : imageData
                },
                beforeSend : function() {
                    $("#comment2").text("Start ajax " + imageData.length);
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    $("#comment2").text("Uploaded! " + data);
                },
                error : function(request, error) {
                    $("#comment2").text("Error! " + error);
                }
            });
        });
        })

    function capturePhotoEdit(source) {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
            quality : 50,
            destinationType : destinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType : source
        });
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {

        console.log(imageData);

        var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

        smallImage.style.display = 'block';

        smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        myData = imageData;
        $("#comment").text(imageData.length);

    }
</script>
<h1>Hello World</h1>

<p>
    <a href="#" onclick="capturePhotoEdit(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">get
        image</a>
</p>
<p>
    <a href="#" id="getDataFromServer">send image</a>
</p>
<span id="comment2"></span>
<img style="display: none; width: 100px; height: 100px;"
    id="smallImage" src="" />
<span id="imagename"></span>
<span id="comment"></span>
```

the asp.net handler saveImage.ashx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Recepies
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for saveImage
/// </summary>
public class saveImage : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath = "";
            filePath = context.Server.MapPath(".");
            string fileName = RandomString(10);
            string myImage = context.Request.Form["image"];
            if (myImage.Length > 0)
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath + "/upload/" + fileName + ".jpg", Convert.FromBase64String(myImage));
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write("File was saved - " + fileName + ".jpg");
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write("File was not saved");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private static Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);//thanks to McAden
    private string RandomString(int size)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        char ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
            builder.Append(ch);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue (on iOS7). The solution that worked for me was to add the "saveToPhotoAlbum" parameter.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(success, fail, {
    quality: 80,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true
});
```