# How to use input type file in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sencha-touch

How to use html file attribute in phonegap ? so that i can browse any .txt file from my android device and upload it to the server??

I read file transfer method in phonegap documentation but according to that it is possible to upload files to the server only through url.But is it possible in normal way like :

```
<input type=file /><button>upload</button>
```

[input type="file" accept="image/*" doesn't work in phone gap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169652/input-type-file-accept-image-doesnt-work-in-phone-gap) i looked at this link but that says only for images .

But how to upload the text files ?

Any help??

Can anybody answer this?

Answer (score -1):

You can't use input file on Phonegap. It's not supported. You need make something like this:

```
function uploadDatabase(callback) {
// file.entry accessible from global scope; see other tutorial
var filepath = file.entry.fullPath,
    uploadOptions = new FileUploadOptions(),
    transfer = new FileTransfer(),
    endpoint = "http://facepath.com/payload";

uploadOptions.fileKey = "db";
uploadOptions.fileName = "database.db";
uploadOptions.mimeType = "text/plain";

transfer.upload(filepath, endpoint, transferComplete,
                        transferError, uploadOptions);
```

}

in mime type put the type of file

Comment: You can use it since phonegap 2.4.

Answer (score -2):

I wrote this answer "You can't use input file on Phonegap. It's not supported.". Check the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/13862151/1853864

Comment: sorry. I am not looking for only images . I wanna upload files stored in sdcard to server . I mean i want browse option to browse any txt file from the sdcard and upload to the server. Is that possible in phonegap?? Or any other method?

Comment: You already try https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/FileUploader?

Comment: Don't just add the same answer to a question requiring the same answer. Instead, mark the question as duplicate (if it's the case).