# jquery form and image submission

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I am having a simple html form that contains text inputs, text area , files such as uploading images ..for submitting a user details and photo in phonegap(cordoova)!

how could I submit this form data when turning it into phone gap application that contains user registration to his data and photo?

I can able to send the data but how can i upload an image with that data?
i am having a php url like this

```
https://MYWEBSITE/post.php?login=user&password=test&nome=Star&genero=M&estrelas=4&nascimento=13/12/1995
```

when i placed this link in browser i am getting the choose file field

couldn't find the way to upload file and images??

any help???

Comment: Please read this and let me know if it isn't what you're trying to achieve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445840/want-to-upload-a-pic-to-the-server-using-phonegap-in-android

Comment: thanks for the link yes I can upload the photo with that example but here I am talking about uploading both photo and data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation by phonegap [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileUploadOptions)

> params: A set of optional key/value pairs to be passed along in the HTTP request. (Object)

```
    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, "http://some.server.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
```

To view the full example please read documentation link above.

Comment: please see my comment above

Comment: @VenkatReddy if you read the link to the docs that I have linked... It will say that you can `A set of optional key/value paired object to add additional data to the post`. Please read that and view the example above.