# Input type file with inappbrowser

Tags: html, file, input, inappbrowser

file browse button i.e `<input type='file'`  not working when opening a website in an inappbrowser on android.

I have searched a lot but did not find any relevant answer. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What file would you possibly want to browse on a smartphone?

Comment: I just want to upload images from smartphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [File upload with phonegap](http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.in/2012/08/attaching-file-in-cordova-uploading-it.html). Here is an example also. May be this one help you.

### Update

- You may also go for [PHONE GAP File Transfer API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer).
- [How to upload file with Phonegap and JqueryMobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861310/how-to-upload-file-with-phonegap-and-jquerymobile)